# How to new a parameter that the type is other class in Swift?

Tags: android, swift

I am implement in Android. I create a new class as a Group , another class as a node.

In first JAVA file. **Node.java**

```
public class Node {

    byte    id;
    int     type;
    String  name;
    String  bdAddr;
    int     nodePktNum;
}
```

In the Second JAVA file **Group.java**

```
public class Group {

    class LedDevice {
        Node        node;
        int         state;
        boolean     ledOn;
        boolean     validDevice;
        int         rssi;
    }
    private LedDevice[] mLedDevices = new LedDevice[20];
    mLedDevices[i].node.name = "123";
```

In the **Group.java** , it use **`Node node;`** to create a new node object.

I want to do the same thing in iOS Swift , so I create the classlike the following code.
In **Node.Swift**

```
class Node {
    var id: UInt8 = 0
    var type: UInt8 = 0
    var name: String = ""
    var bdAddr: String = ""
    var nodePktNum: UInt8 = 0
}
```

In **Group.swift**

```
class Group {
        class LedDevice {

        }
```

**1. In the **Group.swift** , how to do **`Node node;`** like Android ?**

**2. In Swift , How to do the following code ilke the Android ?**

```
private LedDevice[] mLedDevices = new LedDevice[20];
mLedDevices[i].node.name = "123";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `var node:Node`?

Comment: class Node properties type and nodePktNum should be `Int`

Answer (score 1):

For 1): Use `var node: Node`. This declares `node` as type `Node`

2):

```
private var mLedDevices = [LedDevice]()
mLedDevices[i].node.name = "123"
```

Note that you don't declare the size of `mLedDevices` like you do in Java.